# how to select specific records from mongodb using php

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using the following code:

```
foreach ($record as $doc)
{
    $groupIds[] = $doc['groupId'];
}

$gpids = "'".implode("','",array_unique($groupIds))."'";
$collection5 = $db->chat;
$cursor = $collection5->find(array('groupId' => array('$in' => array($gpids))));

foreach($cursor as $res)
{
     print_r($res);
}
```

but no results will come. Please help me.

Comment: If I am directly pass the values its working that is.$cursor = $collection5->find(array('groupId' => array('$in' => array('1','2','3'))));But if am using the variable $gpids its not working.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `$gpids` is a string and you end up putting one element array in the `$in` query. This should work:

```
$collection5->find(array('groupId' => array('$in' => array_unique($groupIds))));
```